# How to copy iTunes Library from one user profile to another?

Tags: itunes, windows

On my Windows Vista, I use iTunes to synchronize songs, apps, movies and books (items) with my iPod Touch. The iTunes media folder location is C:\Users\thomas\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media which does not have any items in it. All the items in iTunes have their actual data reside in an external hard drive that always has the same drive letters when connected to my PC and I connect it with my PC only while synchronization with the iPod Touch.

Anyway, there are a lot of items added to iTunes and now I have to create a new user profile since my old one got corrupted.

When I create a new user profile and open iTunes, iTunes will not have any items added to it. How do I get all of the items added to iTunes in my old profile to the new one?

I know one way would be to drag-drop all the items from the external hard drive back to iTunes in the new profile. But is there a saner way, that is, to copy some configuration files from the old profile’s X location to the new profile’s X location? Or perhaps, an option in iTunes that will let me do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easist way would be to copy the files in "C:\Users\thomas\Music\iTunes" to the same folder in your new user account.  This should link everything back to the external drive.  The files are:

```
.iTunes Preferences.plist
iTunes Library Extras.itdb
iTunes Library Genius.itdb
iTunes Library.itl
iTunes Music Library.xml
```

Comment: This worked. I had only the last four files and so I moved them to the new profiles location and all my music and movies were there. Although, the apps section showed up in iTunes only when I connected my iPod Touch to the PC. Thanks.